# How to get value on an <td> in JavaScript(.tpl file)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i can't access data from a  in my JavaScript. If it changes anything, I'm using `.tpl` file.

This is my `table body`:

```
<tbody id="taryfy">
    {foreach item=klientTaryfa from=$klientTaryfy}
        <tr {if $klient.id_abonamentu != $klientTaryfa.id_abonament} style="background-color: #ffc9c9" {/if}>
        <td>
             <input type="text" name="data_uruchomienia[]" id="{$klientTaryfa.id_data}" value="{$klientTaryfa.data_uruchomienia}" readonly onclick="displayDatePicker('{$klientTaryfa.id_data}', false, 'ymd', '-'); return false;" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
        </td>
        <td>
             <input type="text" name="data_wylaczenia[]" id="{$klientTaryfa.id_data_wylaczenia}" value="{$klientTaryfa.data_wylaczenia}" readonly  onclick="displayDatePicker('{$klientTaryfa.id_data_wylaczenia}', false, 'ymd', '-'); return false;" style="text-align: center; width: 100%">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="id_abonamentu" id="id_taryfy" style="background-color: #EDF1EE; border: 1px solid #000000; width: 375px;">
                {section name=a loop=$abonament}
                <option value="{$abonament[a].id}" 
                        {if $klient.id_abonamentu=='' && $abonament[a].domyslny==1}
                            selected 
                        {elseif $klient.id_abonamentu == $abonament[a].id}selected{/if} 
                        style="
                        {if $klient.id_abonamentu == $abonament[a].id}color: red;{/if} 
                        {if $abonament[a].nieaktywny==1} background-color: silver; {/if}"
                        >{$abonament[a].nazwa|stripslashes}</option>
                {/section}
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img src="./img/del.png" style="cursor: pointer" class="taryfa_del">                         
        </td>
    </tr>
    {foreachelse}
    <tr id="braktaryfy">
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center">Brak przypisanych taryf</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
</tbody>
```

And i can access `id_taryfy` value, and i can alert it, but when i try do the same with `"{$klientTaryfa.id_data}"` i always get null value. Or it doesn't work at all. I tried change id on some static for example `xyz` and do:

```
var ello = document.getElementById("xyz");
```

But it didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know about tpl files, but from the looks of it, it's server side format, and only values generate by the server are rendered in browser. You will have to check the HTML content to select the elements. It's not the file that  browser will see.